# How to check second option in radio group if false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-group

```
<input type="radio" name="verificado_57" value="0" onclick="save(57)"> OK
<input type="radio" name="verificado_57" value="1" onclick="save(57)"> NO
```

Then, when i get response from mysql, if value is **true** should checked OK, if **false** should checked NO.

Im try this but not work.

```
document.getElementByName('verificado_'+valor.ID_PREGUNTA).checked = valor.RESPUESTA;
```

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with the same ID, `id` should always be unique. Use classes for this

Comment: Fixed, and now?

Comment: Mayhap `valor.RESPUESTA` is a string and always truthy. Also [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a `NodeList` (or `HTMLCollection`) and not a single element. You will have to set the `checked` property on individual elements of those list, using loops or indices.

Comment: I change getElementsByName for getElementByName, and now i should cast valor.RESPUESTA to 1 or 0 ?

Comment: There is no `getElementByName()`. Unless you defined it yourself. Try `document.getElementByName('verificado_'+valor.ID_PREGUNTA)[0].checked = valor.RESPUESTA;`

Comment: You might need to add complete Javascript `code` to see whats going on like what is `valor.RESPUESTA` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer could look something like this:

```
var valor = {
  "ID_PREGUNTA": 57,
  "RESPUESTA": true
}
var s = document.getElementsByName('verificado_' + valor.ID_PREGUNTA);

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  s[i].checked = valor.RESPUESTA;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var valor = {
  "ID_PREGUNTA": 57,
  "RESPUESTA": true
}
var s = document.getElementsByName('verificado_' + valor.ID_PREGUNTA);

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  s[i].checked = valor.RESPUESTA;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="verificado_57" value="0" onclick="save(57)"> OK
<input type="radio" name="verificado_57" value="1" onclick="save(57)"> NO
```

Comment: You would have to compare `valor.RESPUESTA` to `radio.value` and switch those around (NO = false; OK = true) to make it reliable.

Comment: @JavaScript I know, but this should give the OP a good idea on how to proceed, since he haven't provided the data structure of `valor`